# converting date and timestamp to to different format

Tags: linux, for-loop, awk, while-loop, julian-date

experts I have three column data(`date, timing, extrainfo`) saved in a text file named inputdata.file.

In a loop i want to read the data row wise and  want to print the yearjulianday from the first column data.

secondly for the second column data I want to print the output in `hour minute second` format but here i want to minus `60` seconds and want to rewrite the output in same `hour` `minute second` format.Additionally, I donot want to do any operation on third column.

For example In the below attached data the first row contains `2019-01-02 07:41:26.225000   5.49.`From this data at first i just want to convert 2019-01-02 to 2019+its julian day i.e. 2019002.

secondly 07:41:26.225000 should be converted to same hr:min:sec format after deduction of  60 seconds i.e 07:40:26.225000 .Similarly for other rows i want to do the same.

```
2019-01-02 07:41:26.225000   5.49
2019-01-05 19:43:54.185000   5
2019-01-07 19:05:21.165000   5.18
```

expected output

```
2019-01-02 07:41:26.225000   5.49   2019002  07:40:26.225000
2019-01-05 19:43:54.185000   5      2019005  19:42:54.185000   
2019-01-07 19:05:21.165000   5.18   2019007  19:04:21.165000
```

I tried the script as :

```
while read -r line;
do
   echo "$line" ;
   awk '{print $1}'
done < inputdata.file
```

However as i am new to shell scripting, not getting much idea on this.Please help.Thanks.

Comment: I saw this exact question earlier today, but now I can't find it. Please edit your question to include exactly what the output should be.

Comment: You show the exact input. Show the exact output. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to show the exact output: `2019002 07:40:26.225000 5.49` `2019005 19:42:54.185000 5` and so on, for all of your sample input. I have an answer ready to post, but I don't know if the output is correct.

Comment: i updated the expected output @glennjackman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    read -r date time extra <<<"$line"
    IFS=. read -r hms fraction <<<"$time"
    newtimestamp=$(date -d "$hms $date -60 seconds" '+%Y%j %T')
    printf '%s %s.%s\n' "$line" "$newtimestamp" "$fraction" 
done < file | column -t
```

`column` added to prettify the output: remove it if you don't need it.

I added an extra line to the output to show that you have to subtract 60 seconds from both the date and the time.

Input:

```
2019-01-02 07:41:26.225000   5.49
2019-01-05 19:43:54.185000   5
2019-01-07 19:05:21.165000   5.18
2020-01-01 00:00:01.0        foobar
```

output:

```
2019-01-02  07:41:26.225000  5.49    2019002  07:40:26.225000
2019-01-05  19:43:54.185000  5       2019005  19:42:54.185000
2019-01-07  19:05:21.165000  5.18    2019007  19:04:21.165000
2020-01-01  00:00:01.0       foobar  2019365  23:59:01.0
```

Comment: Thanks @glenn Jackman for your smart answer.It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for time functions and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    secs = mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$1" "$2))
    ms   = gensub(/.*\./,"",1,$2)

    print $1" "$2, $3, strftime("%Y%j",secs), strftime("%T.",secs-60) ms
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2019-01-02 07:41:26.225000      5.49    2019002 07:40:26.225000
2019-01-05 19:43:54.185000      5       2019005 19:42:54.185000
2019-01-07 19:05:21.165000      5.18    2019007 19:04:21.165000
```

Comment: why the extra things gets printed 1970001 05:28:59.

Comment: What extra things? The output in my answer is exactly what you show as expected in your question and there's no `1970001 05:28:59` present.

Comment: If you're seeing some output other than what I show, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it and see if that's the issue.

Comment: There are probably some empty lines in the input, so `secs` is close to zero.

Comment: @glennjackman ah, right, that'd do it thanks for figuring that out.